# Ubuntu authentication error login screen auto blinking?

Tags: 12.04, server, authentication, error-handling

I am working on Ubuntu that is launched from an Oracle virtual machine. While logging in it is showing an authentication error.

[image: authentication Error]

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy
no capslock? no any space in the username?

Do you have root account/password?

If not, maybe try this:https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-change-root-password-linux
Boot to Recovery Mode then change your password.